# Verify receipt/subscription

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase

heres the comment i based this post on:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77232#issuecomment-790768659

so basically verifyReceipt is deprecated
my solution was to validate the subscription (in my case) directly, and hopefully this is also validating the receipt (i dont know if it is):
[https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/subscriptions/${purchaseID}](https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/subscriptions/$%7BpurchaseID%7D)

i am not sure if this is a ok solution or if it is well resolved, if not could someone help me with an example of validation using native code...
thanks in advance

Comment: As that thread notes, if you are going to verify the receipt, it is best to do it on a server rather than directly on mobile. Depending on your minimum ios target you may also be able to find a plug in that uses storekit2, which is much simpler and handles validation for you in the operating system.

Comment: Calling the App Store api endpoint from your app is not recommended as you will need to embed a credential in your app. You should use a server to make this call and have your app call an endpoint in your server. (This can be a serverless function in Google or aws etc). That way your credentials are held in your server, not in your app

Comment: I am doing it from the server, I'm using back4App, sorry I forgot to mention that.

I'm asking more about the api rather then from where to do it.